# How do I resolve this linker error (unicode, boost, TCHAR/tstring (visual studio 2008))

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, boost, unicode, linker

We just "ported" our app to Unicode and I am having difficulty with some linking.

I wonder if I may be missing some other flag because I am not sure what the name mangling below means:

This is the link error I get

> Error 31  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class
>   boost::shared_ptr __thiscall
>   ResourceManager::GetImage(class `std::basic_string<unsigned
>   short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class
>   std::allocator<unsigned short>` > const &,bool)"
>   (?GetImage@ResourceManager@@QAE?AV?$shared_ptr@VPngImage@@@boost@@ABV?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@_N@Z)
>   referenced in function "public: long __thiscall ATL::CAxWindowT::QueryHost(struct _GUID const &,void * *)"
>   (?QueryHost@?$CAxWindowT@VCWindow@ATL@@@ATL@@QAEJABU_GUID@@PAPAX@Z)   wndGroupSearch.obj

The method is in the code.  It is declared like so:

```
boost::shared_ptr<PngImage> GetImage(const tstring& name, bool bLocalizedOnly = false );
```

When I run dumpbin on the lib that does not link I get the following:

```
public: class boost::shared_ptr<class PngImage> __thiscall ResourceManager::GetImage(class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > const &,bool))
    ?GetImage@ResourceManager@@QAE?AV?$shared_ptr@VPngImage@@@boost@@ABV?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@_N@Z
```

When I dump the Debug version (That does link correctly) I get the following in the dumpbin for the lib

```
public: class boost::shared_ptr<class PngImage> __thiscall ResourceManager::GetImage(class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > const &,bool)" (?GetImage@ResourceManager@@QAE?AV?$shared_ptr@VPngImage@@@boost@@ABV?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@_N@Z)
?GetImage@ResourceManager@@QAE?AV?$shared_ptr@VPngImage@@@boost@@ABV?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@_N@Z (public: class boost::shared_ptr<class PngImage> __thiscall ResourceManager::GetImage(class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > const &,bool))
```

Is there some boost issue or perhaps a compile or link flag I am missing to fix this?

It works in our debug unicode build, but not in release build.  I have not yet found why the mangled names look different:

?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits 
vs 
?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits

and the friendlier names are:

```
ResourceManager::GetImage(class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > const &,bool)
```

vs

```
ResourceManager::GetImage(class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > const &,bool))
```

wchar_t and GU vs unsigned short _WU

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like there are some references to `basic_string<wchar_t>` and some references to `basic_string<unsigned short>`. This could be because the option

`/Zc:wchar_t` [Treat wchar_t as a native types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dh8che7s%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

is not set consistently for all files.

Comment: thanks.  I will try that.  They do look different and I changed it - it is building now...